# Adding/replacing/patching std libraries

Tags: go, lua

I have a (self-written) runtime library which I have used in various programming projects over the years. It started life as a Pascal library in the early days of Turbo Pascal and has since progressed through incarnations in C, Perl and Lua. I am now contemplating to move this over to Go (not least because there are some interesting parallels between Go and Lua). A good part of Go's std library does more or less what my own libraries do (for instance, the flag package or the regex stuff) in which case I can either use them directly or get away with writing a small interface layer.

Problems start with those packages where my model is too different from Go's for a simple interface layer to hide the differences (a case in point are the directory-walking functions). I see two ways forward: re-implement my code as a Go package; or patch some of the existing Go runtime packages.

I am leaning towards the first option, not least because this will help me to get to grips with the language. Then again, I've often patched source code for my own requirements and I am comfortable with that approach. The changes would be localised and it shouldn't be too difficult to merge future version of Go's runtime library with my changes.

So is it feasible, advisable to do that or do I have to regard the Go sources as read only?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine what might be in your personal library that makes you think that it's worth the effort to patch a whole programming language. Can't be regex handling, that's for sure.

Comment: Obviously you have not really read what I wrote. I specifically said that regexes are NO problem area. And I also said that any changes would be localised and not in any way "patching a whole programming language".

Answer (score 1):

> So is it feasible ... ?

No. Everything will break once you touch the Go stdlib as every package out there relies on the stdlib.

> So is it ... advisable to do that ...?

No, not at all.

> [D]o I have to regard the Go sources as read only?

Yes.

Note that what you call "runtime" is not the Go runtime but the Go's standard library.

Comment: I should have added in my OP that any patch/change would be made in such a way as not to break existing code (in theory, in practice there may be cases where it does happen).

Comment: "that any patch/change would be made in such a way as not to break existing code" then I have to admit I do not have the slightest clue what you are talking about. What are changes that do not change anything? Internal (non API) code refactoring are invisible from the outside, so they are not helpful and all other changes might break existing stuff. When you change flag handling everything that depends on the original way will potentially break.

Comment: Trivial (AND NOT A REAL) example. Some structures in Go's std packages would need to carry more information for my purposes. I can extend those structures with new fields, add some lines in those std functions that use them and the whole thing is still 100% backwards compatible. (Of course, there may be clashes when a new version of those package is released with a new version of Go; that is where the merging part of my question comes in.)

Comment: @tmsg Even your "trivial" example can easily break: Extending a `struct` with additional fields may not be backward compatible, it may even cause a compile-time error. E.g. see this example: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QufqD6yTQ4). It compiles and runs (does nothing though). Now if you add a new `Y int` field to struct `A` (`A` by itself remains "flawless"), it won't even compile anymore: `ambiguous selector c.Y`, see this version on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Jb2LNzo1fR).

Comment: Valid point... though to continue that point... I am patching a library whose source code I can inspect so I am able to avoid this sort of clash. Whether this approach is not too error-prone and also too much trouble to be worth it, is another matter. Probably not and that is why I wrote that I am leaning towards the other option.